# Do I need to release NSString generated using @"..."?

Tags: objective-c

If I make an NSString using the code below, do I need to need to release someString?

```
NSString *someString = @"somestring";
```

Comment: Because constant NSString does not get released, would it cause memory problems if used extensively?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it's a compile time constant string object, so it doesn't need releasing. It's the moral equiv of char *c = "hello world" -- where the string hello world is in global data, and you're assigning the address of this data to the pointer c.

Answer (score 15):

If you created an object via a method call that contains `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy`, or starts with `new` (N-A-R-C = "narc"), then *you are responsible for `releasing` the object*.  If this is not the case, then you can ignore the object.

So in the case of strings:

```
NSString * myString = @"This is a string";
```

I don't see a call there to a NARC method, so you are not responsible for releasing it.  It's really that simple.

Answer (score 2):

No, since it's a compile-time constant string, you do not need to release it. In fact, doing so will likely cause a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

I checked [this case](http://developer.apple.com/safari/articles/creatingrestfulclients.html) is different from `NSString *someThing =  @"someThing";` 
they should release urlString because of

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURLString, queryTerm];
```

Anywhere you use alloc/init you release it no mater what.

Answer (score 0):

So, please check what Apple does under the section "Insert Data Using a POST Request" at the following [link](http://developer.apple.com/safari/articles/creatingrestfulclients.html):

I see a `[urlString release];`, why?

Comment: it's a bug, it shouldn't be released

Comment: There, urlString is created using alloc not a constant string.

Comment: Sorry, kubi is right.  The POST example has a bug.  The others use alloc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a compile-time constant string, there wouldn't be a need to retain it as well. Is it correct?