# iphone: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c

if I run this code:

```
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] init];
xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];
NSLog(@"%@\n",xml);
[xml release];
```

I got:
`2010-09-07 11:45:15.523 test[1312:207] <msg>`
`2010-09-07 11:45:15.527 test[1312:207] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3d52ba0`

I have red the memory guide and I think that:
if i create an object using the `alloc` & `init` methods, I should release that object, but the rule does not play well here, why?

**UPDATED**

it seems that this line `xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];` is the problem.
I replaced it by `xml=@"something";` and it worked.

any idea why I can not use the `stringWithFormat` method here?

**UPDATED**
Thanks for the answers @(Douwe Maan, BoltClock, Rod)

I have updated the code, just testing another way:

```
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat,@"<%@>", @"msg"];
NSLog(@"%@\n",xml);
[xml release];
```

interesting: if i run that code with the debug option enabled i get a message saying:
`*** -[CFString _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3954ab0`

but if i run it without the debugging tool, it never sends a message saying that.

questions:
1. is it normal that the error message will not appear if i am not running the project with the debug tool?
2. so, what is the problem with `initWithFormat`?, is it the same that has `stringWithFormat`? (i think it does not create an autoreleased instance)
3. how may i know that some method returns an autoreleased instance?, is there some naming convention anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `@"some string"` (apparently not, read @BoltClock's second comment) and `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some string with object: %@", someObject]` return an `autorelease`d instance of `NSString`. You can use this object any way you like, but you don't own it (since you didn't `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` it), so you don't have to and shouldn't `release` it yourself.

Also, in your code, you actually have two `NSString` objects, the one you `alloc`'d (on line 1) and the one that is `alloc`'ed for you when you call `stringWithFormat:`, on line 2. On line 2 you're re-pointing the variable `xml` to the second `NSString`, but the first one is still around in memory, so you're creating a memory leak (as you haven't `release`d it)! You didn't have to `alloc` this first one anyway, as your second `NSString` is the only one you're actually using.

So the correct code would be, getting rid of the `release` call and the first `NSString`:

```
NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];
NSLog(@"%@\n", xml);
```

---

Questions:

1. Hmm, I'm not sure why that error would occur in the first place...
2. `init...` should be called after `alloc`'ing something, so it's always `[[Object alloc] initWithSomething]`. The autorelease-version of this is `[Object objectWithSomething]`, which does essentially this: `return [[[Object alloc] initWithSomething] autorelease]`.
3. You don't really need to know what does and does not return an autoreleased object, just what you own, and should thus release, and do not own. You own everything you `alloc`, `copy` or `retain`, and you do not own everything else.

Comment: And to add to that, you should never use convenience methods on something you've already called `init` or `copy` on. It *will* cause a leak, and you *won't* get a chance to release that non-autoreleased object!

Comment: By the way, `@"some string"` is **not** an autoreleased object. It's a compile-time constant string object.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by 'use convenience methods on something you've already called init or copy on'?

Comment: RE your second comment: Seriously? I didn't know that... Got a source for that? (Not that I don't believe you, I'd just like to read it somewhere myself ;) )

Comment: @DouweM: the `xml` variable will be changed to point to the object created using the convenience method (in this case `stringWithFormat:`). The `[[NSString alloc] init]` object will continue to exist in memory but is no longer accessible if nothing else in the program is pointing to it. So it can't be released and you get a leak. As for the compile-time constant string, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687962/do-i-need-to-release-nsstring-generated-using)

Comment: @BoltClock Ah yeah, I already edited my post on that first thing. Will read that post on `@"strings"`.

Comment: what about using `NSString *xml= [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];` ???

Comment: Yup, you can do that too, but as you own the object that way, you have to make sure to release it later on too.

Comment: I have created another question about the latest problem i found, if you're interested, please visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670224/iphone-threads-release-pool-object-release-message-sent-to-deallocated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringWithFormat` in your code. The correct code would be

```
NSString *xml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];
NSLog(@"%@\n",xml);
```

The message `stringWithFormat` allocates in the autorelease pool. It is thus released automatically. You are reusing the `xml` variable and "loosing" the pointer that was first allocated.

If you want to keep the value of xml around, for some reason, you might want to try

```
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *newXml=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];
NSLog(@"%@\n",newXml);
[xml release];
```