# iphone: threads + release pool + [ object release] = "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm having a bad time with some little code running on the iphone.

Basically, i just press a button, it calls `runTest`, it runs `test` method on a background thread. That's why I created an autorelease pool.

if i run the below code i got a beautiful message on the console saying:
`2010-09-07 11:45:15.527 test[1312:207] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3d52ba0`

```
-(void) test {
    NSAutoreleasePool *apool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<%@>", @"msg"];
    NSLog(@"%@\n",xml);
    [xml release];

    [apool release]; // <-- this line throws the error msg  
}

- (IBAction) runTest: (id)sender
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(test) withObject:nil];

}
```

I have found that: if I do not run `test` on a background thread (no autorelease pool), just calling `[self test]`, the code works fine.

So, i think the problem is around the thread + autorelease pool, what am I doing wrong? and how may I solve it?

P.S. I have the `NSZombie` flag enabled.

Comment: I created a simple test case app with exact code given above, and it works fine with zero errors. More than likely there's some code you're omitting which is the culprit.

Comment: Quick question: why do you need the autorelease pool here?

Comment: You always need an autorelease pool when using the Cocoa or iOS Objective-C APIs.  When doing threading yourself, you have to manually manage pools.

Comment: @David Liu: please, try this:  1. enable NSZombieEnabled and NSDebugEnabled (on executables) 2. add a break point on `[xml release]` line and also on `[apool release]` line

Comment: 3. run the project using the debuger.

Comment: @jhon: Tried it. Didn't run into any problems, as it shouldn't. None of those would cause an overrelease on anything. So again, you're likely omitting some code that's not present here.

Comment: @David Liu: i have created a small project (with Xcode 3.2.3), if you do not mind, please try it: http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/100908055636-87937.zip

Comment: @jhon: Again, works without a single problem.

Comment: I'm having that same problem, did you find out where the problem was

Answer (score 0):

NSLog may have to send a message to the UI thread (perform selector on main thread) to print serialized to the console, by which time, your xml is already released.

Comment: interesting, I deleted: `NSLog(@"%@\n",xml);` and the problem remains
`

Comment: Good guess, but wrong -- NSLog does its thing on whatever thread it is called on.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter in this case, but you should always `drain` pools and never `release` them.

That is a truly bizarre error, if that is all the code.

The first thing I'd suggest is running the code with zombie detection enabled while recording all retain/release events in Instruments.  That'll give you an inventory of retain/releases on the offending object.  Post the results if it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-autorelease` on the object `xml` instead? This will add it to the active pool, `apool`. Declaring `drain` is better than declaring `-release` - they're the same in a non-garbage collection environment, but some day Apple may implement garbage collection on the iPhone. Hope this helps.