# Where to store fixed NSString variables in Cocoa Application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have different classes, that have NSString fixed variables (like @"/Users/user/media", or xml commands). I think to store everything in class is a bad design.
What is the best place to store fixed NSStrings? Might something like preferences file?

P.S. I'm new in Cocoa, please describe it with details,  how I can store, and read that values. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean strings that are constant throughout an application/class?

Comment: Yes. Like constants paths, or XML requests.

Comment: In general, you should *never* hard-code paths. There are several APIs for obtaining the locations of system-provided folders (such as `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` and `NSHomeDirectory()`), and you should construct your path strings using the result of these methods/functions and by using the `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` method of `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are many ways, but I like to do this in my class implementation files:

```
NSString *const ABConstantStringname = @"name";
```

Where `AB` is the name spacing you're using (if you are using one), and `ConstantStringName` is some meaningful name for the constant.

Then later, you can just use the `ABNameIdentifier` variable whenever you like. You [don't release it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687962/do-i-need-to-release-nsstring-generated-using).

Comment: Thanks!Is it good idea to have constant , path like @"/Users/" ?

Comment: Well if you want a path *string*, then the above is fine.

Comment: It is *not* a good idea to hard-code the path to `/Users`. Please read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/ManipulatingPaths.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scope - if you want to just une in implementation you can just put in .m, but if you want to expose publically to the consumers of the class (outside your .m implementation) you need to also extern it.

**In header:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

extern NSString* const BNRTableBgColorKey;
extern NSString* const BNREmptyDocKey;

@interface PreferenceController : NSWindowController
{
    ...
```

**In implementation:**

```
- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"init");

    NSString * const BNRTableBgColorKey = @"TableBackgroundColor";
    NSString * const BNREmptyDocKey = @"EmptyDocumentFlag";
```