# creating an NSString in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I need to release NSString generated using @“…”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687962/do-i-need-to-release-nsstring-generated-using)

There are two ways to create an NSString obj in Objective C

Way 1:

```
// string1 will be released automatically 

NSString* string1 = [NSString string]; 

// must release this when done
```

Way 2

```
NSString* string2 = [[NSString alloc] init]; 

[string2 release];
```

If I do

```
NSString *string = @"This is a string";
```

My question is which way an above declaration falls in and should we **release** it after all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String constants are not to be released; they're neither explicitly to be released neither autoreleased; they're simply constants and never deallocated.

So, only -release them if you previously retained them.

Comment: String constants are never deallocated. You can return them from a function and they will still be valid.

Answer (score 2):

in the first and last one, you don't own(allocated and initialized) the string so don't release them. while in the 2nd one you have allocated it manually so you must have to release it. if you are using Objects in your code, you should use 2nd one else use first or last one

Comment: very basic question. when you mentioned **own the string**, you meant **allocate and initialize it**. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you own the string, means you allocate it. init is just a instance method to make sure the instance is in a proper state

Comment: yeah bt this jst to explain, for whom who knows the depth level, will autometically get the whole by word OWN

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ARC you should not hafto release at all just put `string = nil;`
however no you do not need to release that

Comment: Use ARC, there is very little reason not to. It makes developing easier and more robust.

Answer (score 1):

if you `alloc` it, then you should `release` it.

strings created through `static` method like

```
[NSString stringWithXXXX];
```

are `auto released`

@H2CO3 is right about constants.